# property not loaded in spring boot client application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am writing Rest Client for a Rest service in Spring boot 1.5.6. Below is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(My.class, args);
    MyClient.saveAction(...parameters here....);
  }

}
```

Below is MyClient class that call rest service:

```
@Component
public class MyClient {

  @Value("${my.rest.uri}")
  private static String MyUri;

  /**
   * Log user actions.
   */
  public static void saveAction(..parameters..) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String queryParameters = String.format("...parameters...");
    restTemplate.postForObject(MyUri + "?" + queryParameters,null, ResponseEntity.class);
  }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
spring.main.banner_mode=off
my.rest.uri=http://localhost:9082/test/api/v1/testapi
```

The problem is that *my.rest.uri* property is not loaded from application.properties file. As a result, i get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
    at com.my.client.service.myClient.saveAction(MyClient.java:40)
```

Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `static` nature of your variable. Spring's `@Value` doesn't work there. So either remove the static method and variable (recommended if you're using singleton scoped beans) or use a non-static initialiser. Here are the options:

### Use non-static methods

```
@Component
public class MyClient {

  @Value("${my.rest.uri}")
  private String MyUri;

  /**
   * Log user actions.
   */
  public void saveAction(..parameters..) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String queryParameters = String.format("...parameters...");
    restTemplate.postForObject(MyUri + "?" + queryParameters,null, ResponseEntity.class);
  }
}
```

### Non-static initialiser

```
@Component
public class MyClient {


  private static String MyUri;

  /**
   * Log user actions.
   */
  public static void saveAction(..parameters..) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String queryParameters = String.format("...parameters...");
    restTemplate.postForObject(MyUri + "?" + queryParameters,null, ResponseEntity.class);
  }


  public void setMyUri( @Value("${my.rest.uri}") String uri) {
       MyUri = uri;
  }


}
```